# login:1 GET http://localhost:3000/manifest.webmanifest 404 (Not Found)

Tags: html, css, node.js, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

i created a todo list app using nodejs and wanted to add PWA (add to home screen feature) , on adding manifest.js file the browser console shows the following errors.

> login:1 GET http://localhost:3000/**manifest.webmanifest** 404 (Not Found)
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

*inside header.ejs*

```
<link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="/manifest.webmanifest" >
```

*inside manifest.json*

```
{
    "short_name":"Slate",
    "name":"SLATE (The Online Scheduler)",
    "description":"A simple To-Do list application.",
    "icons":[
      
      {
        "src":"images/logophone.png",
        "type":"image/png",
        "sizes":"187x91"
      },
      {
        "src":"images/logo.png",
        "type":"image/png",
        "sizes":"519x151"
      }
    ],
    "start_url":"home.ejs",
    "display":"standalone",
    "background_color":"#45ff61",
    "theme_color":"#45ff61",
    "scope":"/"
}
```

[image: browser image]

[image: todolist folder public -css views -header.ejs -home.ejs app.js manifest.json]

struggling hard to solve it ..kindly help

Comment: Why do you expect the server to provide the content of that JSON file when the client asks for that URL?

Comment: If m not wrong you are asking me to add app.get("/manifest ") ?? Is it?

Comment: You haven't provided the server side code you think should perform a response other than 404 for that URL so … maybe? Except the URL is `/manifest.webmanifest` not `/manifest `

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `<link rel="manifest"` tag is pointing to the wrong file. Your code points to `manifest.webmanifest`, but your actual filename is `manifest.json`.

Change the line in *header.ejs* to:

```html
<link rel="manifest" crossorigin="use-credentials" href="/manifest.json">
```

Comment: thanku for replying...but I tried this this too ...gives the error as no resource found ...

Comment: If you try to make a request for the file on its own, does it work?

Comment: actually it don't  .. I added  app.get("/",function(req,res){ res.sendFile(__dirname+"c:\users\pallavi\....")});      again it gives me same error  line1,column1,syntax error   and manifest. Json not found

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but fixed it with a few changes.

First of all I have change my file FROM `manifest.webmanifest` TO `manifest.json` and I have done the same in `href`, but it was not enough I still received an error (404).

Then I added my top root folder in and it worked.

My `index.html` was in `task` folder

My `manifest.json` file in `task/favicon` folder.

Link in `index.html` looked like this:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/task/favicon/manifest.json" >
```

Or try to add `./` at the beggining, it means "on the same level", that worked for me too.

```
<link rel="manifest" href="./favicon/manifest.json" >
```

I hope it will help someone out.